# Max and min of values of an array of an array

Tags: python

I have values of an array within another array such that print(array) returns something such as

```
[array([A1, B1]), array([A2,B2]), array([A3, B3 ])]
```

How would I obtain the max values of A and B? Currently I'm trying numpy.amax() but that only returns max between either not both.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your full code and expected IO?

Comment: It seems you are mixing python-arrays and numpy-arrays. np.amax() is for nD-numpy-arrays. You have a python array of 1D numpy arrays. You should probably use a 2D numpy array of size 3x2. Then amax() will work. It will also improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, supposing you want the max values of each array within your array you could do this:

```
arr = [[A1, B1], [A2,B2], [A3, B3 ]]
max_vals = [max(a) for a in arr]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all in python its not a array , its list
Below code will resolve your problem

```
lst = [list([A1, B1]), list([A2,B2]), list([A3, B3 ])]
for i in list:
   lst[i].sort()
   print lst[i][-1]
```

That will give max value in each list in the main list